# Custom tracking code executing twice

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I just built this landing page: [defensalegal.us](http://defensalegal.us/) and I added some simple tracking to get custom data to be displayed on a stats page. For some reason, when the page loads, it gets executed twice and records it as 2 page views. I only have the tracking on the home page and even if another page is viewed it somehow appears as a single page view. Even if the file being viewed is in another folder. Any clue as to why?

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);

$insert = 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' (ID, ip, views, name, email, phone, message, timestamp) VALUES("", "'.$ip.'", "1", "", "", "", "", "'.date('Y-m-d').' @ '.date('H:i:s').'")';

$select = 'SELECT * FROM '.$table.' WHERE ip = "'.$ip.'"';

$result = $conn->query($select);
if($result->num_rows > 0){
    //echo "Record found".'</br/>';
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $views = $row['views'] + 1;

        $update = 'UPDATE '.$table.' SET views = "'.$views.'", timestamp = "'.date('Y-m-d').' @ '.date('H:i:s').'" WHERE ip = "'.$ip.'"';

        if($conn->query($update) === TRUE){
            //echo 'Record updated successfully'.'</br/>';
        } else {
            //echo "Error: ".$insert."<br>".$conn->error;
        }
}elseif($result->num_rows == 0){
    if($conn->query($insert) === TRUE){
        //echo 'New record created successfully'.'</br/>';
    } else {
        //echo 'Record already exists';
    }
}
```

The same kind of thing is happening on the thank you page after filling out the form. 1 email is sent, but the email copy is as follows: Name: Email: Phone: Message: Name: Email: Phone: (The Message field doesn't get repeated for some reason.) and it's counted as a view, which should only occur when the home page is viewed. The only sql statement I have on the thank you page is:

```
    $update = 'UPDATE '.$table.' SET name = "'.$name.'", email = "'.$email.'", phone = "'.$phone.'", message = "'.$message.'", timestamp = "'.date('Y-m-d').' @ '.date('H:i:s').' - filled out form" WHERE ip = "'.$ip.'"';
```

But the `view` column gets updated as well.

This is the file structure:

- /index.php
- /login.php
- /stats/index.php
- /thankyou/index.php

If you want to see it in action, just go to `login.php` and use these credentials: **defensa ndmr123**
(It's perfectly safe to use, and has no relation to the database login. It's just a static, temporary login that's written right into the php on the page.)

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put user data of any kind, like from `$_POST`, directly into a query.

Comment: @tadman Thank you for the tip. That is very useful and good to know.